# Wordpress: have a nav menu full width

Tags: css, wordpress

I use wordpress 3.9.1 and i would like to have a navigation menu full width. 
The theme i use is Maya with a fixed layout and there are these rules regarding the css

```
#nav {
margin: 30px 0 20px 0;
border-top: 1px solid #CFCFCF;
border-bottom: 1px solid #CFCFCF;
text-align: center;
}

#nav ul {
list-style: none;
margin: 0px;
font-size: 12px;
}
```

Now, i've transformed into:

```
#nav {
margin: 30px 0 20px 0;
border-top: 1px solid #CFCFCF;
border-bottom: 1px solid #CFCFCF;
text-align: center;
    position:absolute; left:0;right:0;
 }

#nav ul {
list-style: none;
font-size: 12px;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto; width:100%; max-width: 2000px;
   }
```

but it does not work,  remains inside its fixed container.

How can I do?

edit:
header.php

```
<!-- START NAV -->
                <div id="nav" class="group">
                    <?php  
                        $nav_args = array(
                            'theme_location' => 'nav',
                            'container' => 'none',
                            'menu_class' => 'level-1',
                            'depth' => apply_filters( 'yiw_main_menu_depth', 5),   
                            //'fallback_fb' => false,
                            //'walker' => new description_walker()
                        );

                        wp_nav_menu( $nav_args ); 
                    ?>    
                </div>
                <!-- END NAV -->
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to the site, or a sample of the fixed layout theme?

Comment: you can see the site here: http://www.studiosdz.com/famot

Comment: There's no good css-only technique to do what you are after. You will need to drastically alter the markup for the nav to be full width.  Basically, you'll need to remove the single "wrapper", and place a "wrapper" element around each "strip" or "row" that you want to be contained within the fixed width, and elements such as the slideshow and your nav will need to *not* be within a wrapper, so they are allowed to stretch full width.

Comment: i solved moving all the nav code ( the one posted above) ouside of <div class="group inner">